# Scala JPA in netbeans

Tags: scala, netbeans

I am learning Java EE 6 but wants my Entities in scala and am also using netbeans. I created a scala class library but I cannot use javax.persistence._ even if I add the eclipselink library I can't import it. NB: I've tried eclipse but always having problems especially with glassfish thus I want to use netbeans and have java web project depend on the scala class library. I also like vim and netbeans have a perfect plugin for that. Not dishing eclipse but I am always suffering when I tried to use eclipse with Java EE 6 compared to netbeans.

Comment: It sounds like the JPA API Jar isnt on the classpath.  Could that be?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Maven to configure your dependencies for JavaEE and your specific JPA provider, for example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>toplink.essentials</groupId>
    <artifactId>toplink-essentials</artifactId>
    <version>2.1-60f</version>
</dependency>
```

Notes:

- To use javax.persistence classes, you need javax.persistence dependency.
- Im using Java EE 7 but in your case, change "7.0" to "6.0"
- Toplink is my JPA provider (you can use EclipseLink, Hibernate, ...), for example:

> ```
>  <dependency>
>    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
>    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
>    <version>2.6.0</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

Or another provider at this link: 
[JPA provider](http://mvnrepository.com/search?q=jpa%20provider)